# What is meant by the vacuum structure of ABJM theory?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, terminology, supersymmetry, vacuum, chern-simons-theory

I was reading the paper [Large $N$ behavior of mass deformed ABJM theory](https://arxiv.org/abs/1512.00249). It talks about the vacuum structure of the (mass deformed) ABJM thoery. What does vacuum structure mean in general or in reference to the ABJM theory?

Comment: It probably means the structure/geometry of the moduli space of vacua which is typically a non-trivial algebraic variety in supersymmetric theories. In other words, the vacuum is not usually unique in such theories - the space of vacuum states forms a variety of some sort.